# Moving between views

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am moving between views in same storyboard like this:

```
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Next" sender:self];
```

It works, it moves to second view. In second class i have declared a timer, when second view loads it starts to run and it starts to move some objects. Also works fine, but it starts to move objects for two seconds and than it moves objects back in original positions and starts move them again. After that in runs just okay. I don't know why it restarts it for the first time when i move to that view?

```
(secondClass.m file)

- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
   [super viewDidLoad]
   move=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(moveObject) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

 }

-(void)moveObject
 {
   obj1.center = CGPointMake(obj1.center.x-1, obj.center.y);
 }
```

Comment: we need the code from `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` of your second class

Comment: Not sure,but my guess is that your timer should invalidate after moving to the other view controllers

Comment: Have you implemented `viewDidSublayout` in case of IOS7?

Comment: Timer move is declared in secondClass.h file. So it starts fresh on view load.

Comment: This could be a consequence of using auto layout. Do you have that turned on (it's on by default, so if you haven't turned it off, it's on)? You can test if this is the problem by turning it off in IB. If you want to leave it on, then you need to  move your objects by adjusting constraints rather than setting frames.